# Collate all Worksheet Names in a Master sheet with Referenced Formulas

Tags: vba, worksheet

With the code below (creating a new worksheet), I would like for the new worksheet name to be added in a Master sheet (Column A) - note that multiple sheets will be inserted. Aside from listing all worksheet names in a 1 Master sheet, I would also like to reference (formula) some data from each worksheet (Ranges FX to GU) to Master sheet Range B to X - note that Column A has been pre-populated as mentioned above.

```
Sub NewBlankForm()
'Creates a new worksheet
 
    Dim ShtName As String
    Dim Flg As Boolean
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do Until Flg
        ShtName = InputBox("Enter the name of the item to be reviewed." _
            + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Name must not contain any of these characters: " _
            + vbNewLine + "\ / ? * [ ] :")
        If ShtName = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Len(ShtName) > 31 Then
            MsgBox ("The name is too long.")
        ElseIf Evaluate("isref('" & ShtName & "'!F3)") Then
            MsgBox ("That name is taken.")
        Else
            Flg = True
        End If
    Loop
    Sheets("template").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("template").Copy after:=Worksheets("Read me")
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = ShtName
        .Range("F3").Value = ShtName
    Sheets("template").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox vbNewLine + ActiveSheet.Name & " tab created", , "Success!"
    
End Sub
```

[image: this is how the Master sheet looks like, in each cell shows the would-be formula per inserted worksheet]

Comment: You are pasting values (`xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`) so it's not clear where the formula comes into play here. Where are the formulas stored? What sheet should they be referencing? Unclear if you need help with existing code or next steps. Is something wrong with your current code?

Comment: @undearboy, right, that was my original plan, to just copy and paste. I am asking for help on how I can modify it to be able to automatically reference (formula) the Master tab to other worksheets as they are created by the first code above.

The master sheet has a table (A1 to X1)... I would like for it to simply copy (by referencing it to each worksheet range FX to GU), this way any changes in the other worksheets will still reflect in the Master. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So the info you shared here isn't really relevant (*the source of the new sheet doesn't have much to do with your problem statement*). You will need to update your question to share details about your master sheet. What are the formulas? Where? etc.....

Comment: What you could do is store a 'dummy' formula that references a non-existent sheet. Then you can just use something like `Find & Replace` to swap the temp name in formula to the sheet name (`Range("F3").Value)` and move the formulas to the appropriate space. Ex: Dummy formula = `SUM(TempSheet!C14:C21)`. So you just need to replace `TempSheet` with `Range("F3").Value`. Depending on the design of the master sheet, this may do the trick. But we don't know because you have not shared those details

Comment: Show us a sample of your master sheet and show us what is added when a new sheet is added AND show us some sample formulas. There is not enough info here to actually help outside of general advice

Answer (score 0):

Against my best judgement (*given lack of information*) i'm going to provide a few solutions.

---

First you need to add your new sheet name to the master sheet. To do this just call this macro at the end of existing macro with `Master_Update ShtName` which will pass the name as a variable. Then you just drop this in the first available row in `Column A`

```
Sub Master_Update(ShtName As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master") 

Dim lr As Long
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

ws.Range("A" & lr) = ShtName

End Sub
```

---

### INDIRECT

Depending on your formula, you can use `INDRECT` to dynamically reference sheets. You would just point to the sheet name you have stored in `COLUMN A` to auto complete. Here is an example of the formulas dynamically referencing 3 separate sheets

[image]

---

### REPLACE

You can also use the VBA function [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function). To do this you would just copy the formulas, and replace the prior worksheets name reference (which can be determined with `Column A` and replace it with the current sheets name (`Column A, last row`)